# New hashtable entry overwrites the value of another key - Java

Tags: java, hashtable, overwrite

I am struggling with this hashtable problem (new to Java). The program receives instances of an event ADD_info, which then runs the "public ADD_info()" method. For every instance I want to write a key/value pair into a hashtable (key: TASK.value, value: INFO_add.value - both variables are filled externally with the ADD_info event). I can add one entry, but when I enter a second one, the value entry of the first one gets overwritten. The simplified code is given below, with the program output.

```
public class ProdInfo_SIFB extends fb.rt.FBInstance {
    /** EVENT ADD_info */
    public final EventInput ADD_info = new EventInput(this);

    /** EVENT ADDED */
    public final EventOutput ADDED = new EventOutput();

    /** VAR TASK:WSTRING */
    public WSTRING TASK = new WSTRING();

    /** VAR INFO_add:WSTRING */
    public ARRAY INFO_add = new ARRAY(new WSTRING(), 5);;

    Hashtable Product_info = new Hashtable();  //instantiate hashtable

    public ProdInfo_SIFB(){
        super();
    }
    public void serviceEvent(EventServer e){

        if (e == ADD_info) service_ADD_info();
    }

    /** Services the ADD_info event. */
    public void service_ADD_info(){

        System.out.println("TASK.value = " + TASK.value);  //display TASK.value content
        //display entries of INFO_add array as received from external source
        for(int j = 0; j < INFO_add.value.length; j++){
            System.out.println("INFO_add_" + j + ":" + INFO_add.value[j].toString());
        }

        Product_info.put(TASK.value, INFO_add.value);  //add key and value to hashtable

        System.out.println("No. of Keys = " + Product_info.size());

        // Display all elements in hash table.
        Enumeration tasks = Product_info.keys();
        while(tasks.hasMoreElements()) {
            String str = (String) tasks.nextElement();
            ANY[] info = (ANY[]) Product_info.get(str);
            System.out.println(str + ": ");
            for(int i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
                System.out.println("info_" + i + ": " + info[i].toString());
            }
        }

        ADDED.serviceEvent(this);
    }
}
```

The entries of the INFO_add array and the hashtable look as follows for the first instance:

```
TASK.value = "TASK1"
INFO_add_0:"1"
INFO_add_1:"2"
INFO_add_2:"3"
INFO_add_3:"4"
INFO_add_4:"5"

/** HASHTABLE ENTRIES */
No. of Keys = 1
TASK1
info_0: "1"
info_1: "2"
info_2: "3"
info_3: "4"
info_4: "5"
```

Then, for the second instance:

```
TASK.value = "TASK2"
INFO_add_0:"11"
INFO_add_1:"22"
INFO_add_2:"33"
INFO_add_3:"44"
INFO_add_4:"55"

/** HASHTABLE ENTRIES */
No. of Keys = 2
TASK1
info_0: "11"
info_1: "22"
info_2: "33"
info_3: "44"
info_4: "55"
TASK2
info_0: "11"
info_1: "22"
info_2: "33"
info_3: "44"
info_4: "55"
```

which shows the value of the first key, TASK1, being overwritten.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Also, please excuse some of the naming conventions - some of it was automatically generated by FBDK.

Regards
Karel

Comment: Can you provide a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org) that focuses on the main issue (Adding values to hash tables in this case)

Comment: Probably best to read the [HashTable documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), your `HashTable<String, String>` works as expected, but you want something like `HashTable<Strint, List<String>>` or a MultiMap

Comment: This will save you a lot of time, and get you better answers: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java)

Comment: @jlordo He doesn't want a List of values. He wants one value for each key.

Comment: I edited the question - I hope it is more understandable!

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you reuse the same INFO_add instance every time you insert new key/value pair, what you really need to do is to create new instance of `new ARRAY(new WSTRING(), 5);` every time you start working with next record set.

I am not sure where do you fill data for INFO_add but you can reinitialize it just after you put it into Product_info:

```
Product_info.put(TASK.value, INFO_add.value);  //add key and value to hashtable
INFO_add = new ARRAY(new WSTRING(), 5); // add this line
```

Comment: The INFO_add array is actually an input data variable to the Service Interface Function Block I am working with. FBDK actually generated most of the code automatically. So every time the event ADD_info occurs, the data of INFO_array is updated. I tried the reinitialization now - it still wrongly updates the value of TASK1 and now sets the value of TASK2 as null (empty). Can you explain why the value of TASK1 gets wrongly updated?? I appreciate the help!!

Comment: You can't reuse the same object if you want the values for TASK1 and TASK2 to be different and independent.

Comment: Then I suggest to copy values from INFO_array to a new array and then put that array into hashtable.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the object you added to the map with key "TASK1" is modified after being put in the map. I bet something like this is happeneing;

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.setValue("1","2",3");
map.put("TASK1", obj);
obj.setValue("11","22",33");
map.put("TASK2", obj);
```

Putting an object in the map doesn't make a copy of it, so you end up with two map entries both pointing to the same value.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the code presented is what is currently happening in the program...? If so, how can I fix it (i.e. not overwrite value entries)?